# Bootstrap menu cover header of Div when I scroll

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm using bootstap menu for my web page, but when I click over second menu, he cover header of DIV, like in this image.
[image]

HTML code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top top-nav-collapse navbar-out-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
                    <img src="https://placehold.it/153X50">
                </a>                    
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" aria-expanded="false" style="height: 0px;">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">                 
                    <li class="scroll"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
                    <li class="scroll active"><a href="#services">Menu 1</a></li>                     
                    <li class="scroll"><a href="#doctors">Menu 2</a></li>
                    <li class="scroll"><a href="#about-us">Menu 3</a></li> 
                    <li class="scroll"><a href="#gallery">Gallery</a></li>
                    <li class="scroll"><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>       
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

CSS code:

```
@media(min-width:767px) {
.navbar {
    padding: 20px 0;
    -webkit-transition: background .5s ease-in-out,padding .5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: background .5s ease-in-out,padding .5s ease-in-out;
    transition: background .5s ease-in-out,padding .5s ease-in-out;
}


}
```

Can i resolve this problem with jQuery?

Comment: Please give the full code

Answer (score 0):

give padding to the section
**for example:**

```
#services {
   padding:100px 0;
}
```

the padding must be more than the **navbar** height

Comment: But in my design, I don't have 100px of padding-top. I tried with this, but isn't right solution

Comment: this must solve it. I expect you didn't use box-sizing:border-box

Answer (score 0):

Have you altered the z-index?

check the z-index, press F12 for developer option.

Post the complete HTML code

Comment: Add complete html code of the page, what you have posted has code of Nav only

Answer (score 0):

You require some Body padding

The fixed navbar will overlay your other content, Instead of adding padding to every single container div. You can add some padding to ''. By default, the navbar is 50px high. You need to add padding more than height of your navbar.

```
body{
    padding-top: 70px;
}
```

If this doesn't work then add class="clearfix" to your container div (second line in your code)